# CNAME changes the url of my meteor website on the browser

Tags: meteor, heroku, amazon-route53

I deployed my meteor app on Heroku and wanted to use a custom domain name purchased on Route 53.

Thanks to [this tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53), example.com and www.example.com are redirected to example.herokuapp.com. However, when I type example.com or www.example.com, the url changes to example.herokuapp.com and I would keep my custom domain in the browser.

I wonder if it comes from the ROOT_URL env variable set to example.herokuapp.com in Heroku. I tried to change the ROOT_URL to example.com but then, the website wasn't reachable anymore.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I forced HTTPS through a meteor package. For obscures reasons, http://example.com was redirection to https://example.herokuapp.com.

I set CloudFront with SSL and now the redirection works properly without changing the URL.